# Xcode 6 Change default template for new file

Tags: xcode6

In Xcode 6, how do I change the default template Xcode choses when creating a new file.

Right now, the template chooser (first screen when creating a new file) defaults to:
    OS X - Source - Cocoa Class

I want it to default to:
    IOS - Source - Cocoa Touch Class

You'd think the when you create an IOS project, Xcode would then default to choosing IOS templates ... but, it doesn't appear to do that.